# Delete a range of files, skip a range, then repeat

Tags: python, windows, file

I'd like to get a code up and running for a project. I'm familiar with python for Maya, but struggling with working with files in windows. Basically I want to delete 64 files in a list, skip the next 64 files, then repeat.

### The code I've got so far is:

```
     import os

     fileList = os.listdir("C:\Users\Tory\Desktop\Delete_Test")
     count = 1
     for F in fileList:
     if count < 64:
         os.remove(F)
         time.sleep(2)
         count = count + 1
     elif count < 128:
         count = count + 1
     else:
         count = 1
```

---

The error I get is "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'HandDrawn_Access_IQ_Comp_14000.jpg'"

I don't understand how it isn't finding the file that it is telling me exists based on where I told it to look. Is there some kind of formatting I'm missing? I'm working on windows if that matters.

Thanks so much!

Comment: And what do you see if you `print(os.listdir("C:\Users\Tory\Desktop\Delete_Test"))`? Is it a list of absolute paths?

Comment: Hi when I print that, I get: "'HandDrawn_Access_IQ_Comp_14000.jpg', 'HandDrawn_Access_IQ_Comp_14001.jpg', 'HandDrawn_Access_IQ_Comp_14002.jpg', 'HandDrawn_Access_IQ_Comp_14003.jpg', 'HandDrawn_Access_IQ_Comp_14004.jpg', 'HandDrawn_Access_IQ_Comp_14005.jpg'...."

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `join`

Something like:

```
directory = "C:\\Users\\Tory\\Desktop\\Delete_Test"
for F in os.listdir(directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution to remove batches of 64 files with `n` number of files in the directory

```
import os
import itertools

folder = "C:\Users\Tory\Desktop\Delete_Test"
files = os.listdir(folder)
print("Total number of files in the folder: {0}".format(len(files)))

skip = 64
sets = len(files) / skip
breaks = [(i*skip, i*skip+skip-1) for i in xrange(sets) if i % 2]

files_to_delete = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([files[start:stop] for start, stop in breaks]))
print("No of files to be deleted: {0}".format(len(files_to_delete)))

for filename in files_to_delete:
    filepath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    print("Deleting file: {0}".format(filepath))
    os.remove(filepath)
```

Comment: I tried a the solutions listed here, they don't throw up any errors, but they don't delete files either.

Comment: @PolyGoop I have added print statements for debugging. I tested this in a Unix Environment, the issue might be with the way you specify file paths in Windows. The print statements should be able to help you find the issue.